# A field name was provided without a field value in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php

Tags: magento2, log, magento2.3.5

After installed Magento 2.3.5, I check my log file and it show an issue:

```
[12-May-2020 18:29:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Laminas\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A field name was provided without a field value in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php:193
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php(156): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaderLine('Mozilla/5.0 (Wi...')
#1 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(237): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaders(Array)
#2 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(85): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->setServer(Object(Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters))
#3 vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(136): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct()
#4 vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php(123): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieReader), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUti in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php on line 193
[12-May-2020 18:29:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Laminas\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A field name was provided without a field value in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php:193
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php(156): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaderLine('Mozilla/5.0 (Wi...')
#1 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(237): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaders(Array)
#2 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(85): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->setServer(Object(Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters))
#3 vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(136): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct()
#4 vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php(123): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieReader), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUti in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php on line 193
[12-May-2020 18:29:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Laminas\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A field name was provided without a field value in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php:193
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php(156): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaderLine('Mozilla/5.0 (Wi...')
#1 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(237): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaders(Array)
#2 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(85): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->setServer(Object(Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters))
#3 vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(136): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct()
#4 vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php(123): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieReader), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUti in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php on line 193
[12-May-2020 18:29:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Laminas\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A field name was provided without a field value in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php:193
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php(156): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaderLine('Mozilla/5.0 (Wi...')
#1 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(237): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaders(Array)
#2 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(85): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->setServer(Object(Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters))
#3 vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(136): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct()
#4 vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php(123): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieReader), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUti in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php on line 193
[12-May-2020 18:29:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Laminas\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: A field name was provided without a field value in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php:193
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php(156): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaderLine('Mozilla/5.0 (Wi...')
#1 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(237): Laminas\Http\Headers->addHeaders(Array)
#2 vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(85): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->setServer(Object(Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters))
#3 vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Request.php(136): Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct()
#4 vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php(123): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieReader), Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUti in vendor/laminas/laminas-http/src/Headers.php on line 193
```

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a similar problem after changing *base_url* into *phpMyAdmin*: I accidentally saved value with tab and line ending characters before URL.
I recomend to set again your base URL by using Magento's CLI:

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://yourdomain.com/"
```

Also secure URL, if you entered it earlier:

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://yourdomain.com/"
```

Then flush the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: It helps me. Thanks